# Android: AudioTrack leaks to speaker on headphone removed

Tags: android, audiotrack, mute, speaker

I'm building a **MusicPlayer** using **AudioTrack** and want the music to stop playing when the headphones are removed.

I've attached a listener to the headphone removed event, to pause and mute the player.

However when I remove the headphone, the pause and mute events get fired, but a brief millisecond of music gets directed to the speaker..

I've tried the following:
(Both before playback and on headphone removed)

```
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);    
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);    

am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

> I should also mention that I'm writing the audio in a stream using
>   **audioTrack.write(BLOCKING)**. Can anybody help me figure out how to stop
>   the sound leaking to the speakers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself, but incase somebody else runs into the same issue

The event **ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY** is raised immediately, where as **ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG** is raised slightly later..

Use **ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY** if you want to immediately pause your playback